# Can we use Azure DevOps Pipelines to disable some Dynamics 365 custom plugins following deployment?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are using Azure DevOps Pipelines with the https://github.com/WaelHamze/dyn365-ce-vsts-tasks extension to deploy our managed solution to Dynamics 365 online. We enable all plugin steps on deployment. Following deployment, we have a requirement to disable a handful of plugin steps. Currently we do this manually. Anyone aware of how we can automate this in the DevOps Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried it with the "MSCRM Plugin Registration" Task? It is in beta right now but as far as I understood it you can "reset" an assembly and just don't register your steps you want to remove?

Comment: Yes I looked at it, but that needs a reference to the assembly DLL that I don't have at that point in the deployment pipeline. I'm deploying a managed solution.zip file, which will have the assembly embedded. I want to selectively turn off some steps post-deployment.

Comment: To be honest, I think the only way is to create your own custom task to achieve this. Maybe you can use power shell to do what you want, [like in this example](https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell.Samples/blob/master/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell.Samples/DisablePluginSteps/DisablePluginSteps.ps1)